# No module named P4API when trying to import P4

Tags: python, windows, perforce, p4v, p4python

I am trying to use Perforce with python. 
When I did the line:

```
import P4
```

The error message I got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 410, in <module>
    import P4API
ImportError: No module named P4API
```

Tried looking at different answers none of them solved my problem...
Seems like P4 has a very messy code management and names of modules kept changing... Someone pls enlighten me with what happens with the python api for p4 and how to install them?

BTW I use Windows 10 64-bit, Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed all the required packages? Where did you get it? Looking at download links on the Perforce site puzzled me, and apparently several components are required.

Comment: Problem solved by running 'pip install --upgrade p4python'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be only P4, not P4API

```
from P4 import P4
```

I don't see any P4API module in P4 package

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I was using **Python3.8** with Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers **Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)**).

Also, I was using p4python **p4python-2019.1.1858212.tar.gz (92.5 kB)** and manually copied in python3.8 installed location.

*pip install p4python* did not work in MS-DOS due to some ssl error.

**Cause:** Python3.8 is the culprit since above p4python was not compatible with it.

**Solution:**

1. Use Python3.7
2. Trigger **pip install p4python** from MSDOS like below:
   *C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python37\Scripts>pip install p4python*
3. p4python gets downloaded and installed successfully in Python3.7. No need to manually download from https://pypi.org/project/p4python/#files
4. Now use P4.connect() like below, it works fine.

   from P4 import P4

   p4 = P4()
   p4.port = "xxxx"
   p4.user = "vivek.goynar"
   p4.client = ""

   p4.connect()